# sample a single element from each key of dictionary randomly

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I have a dictionary where the keys represent groups, and the values are a list of elements (for simplicity let's assume the values are integers).

An example of such a dictionary, `d`, is:

```
d = {2: [0, 1, 7, 8, 9], 1: [2, 4], 4: [3], 3: [5, 6]}
```

I wish to sample this dictionary multiple times randomly, where the sample will consist of a random sampling of a single element from the first group, a single element from the second, etc.

Simple output examples are:

```
[9, 2, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 6]
[7, 4, 3, 6]
...
```

I can iterate over the dictionary, `d`, `M` times and iterate over the keys and sample 1 element, I was wondering if there is a simpler method, hopefully, more efficient as it will be a part of a larger more complex algorithm.

The naive approach is:

```
ll = []
    for i in range(10):
        tmp = []
        for k, l in d.items():
            tmp.append(random.choice(l))
        ll.append(tmp)
    print(ll)  # [[5, 6, 9, 7], [8, 4, 3, 7], [2, 1, 3, 7], [5, 1, 3, 7], [0, 4, 3, 7], [2, 1, 3, 7], [2, 6, 9, 7], [2, 1, 9, 7], [8, 4, 9, 7], [2, 1, 9, 7]]
```

I'm not strict about the dictionary, I can use other structures as well but the logic stays the same.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Check `random.sample` or `random.choice`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: @Mike67 yeah, I'm familiar with them, take a look at my naive approach. I was looking for a different approach.

Comment: You want an option without using a `random` library?

Comment: @Mike67 No, I wanted an option without the need to iterate over the keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't really be an alternative, since you're working with dictionaries and lists. You'll have to iterate over the dictionary values `M` times, as you mention, and take a `random.choice` of each inner list on each iteration. A simple way of doing so would be:

```
from random import choice
n = 5
l = list(d.values())
[list(map(random.choice, l)) for _ in range(n)]
# [[9, 2, 3, 6], [7, 2, 3, 5], [9, 4, 3, 5], [0, 2, 3, 5], [7, 4, 3, 5]]
```

Another way could be to sample from the inner list with replacement using `random.choices`, and then *transpose* the resulting nested list with `zip`. That way we reduce the above to a single iteration over the values:

```
from random import choices
list(zip(*(random.choices(i, k=n) for i in l)))
# [(8, 4, 3, 5), (1, 2, 3, 6), (9, 4, 3, 6), (1, 2, 3, 5), (8, 4, 3, 5)]
```

Comment: Nice one-liner. I guess there isn't a simpler way then that. Do you think its worth using `pandas` maybe?

Comment: Probably overkill @DavidS I'd personally go with lists for this

Comment: Do you mean list of lists? I built the dictionary from the output of `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree` so to split my original list of the element to groups with the proper class. I calculate the distance matrix -> hierarchical clustering -> cutting the tree to `k` groups and then built the dictionary

Comment: Yeh a list of lists, still from the list class @DavidS

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import random

result=[]
for i in range(M):
    result.append([random.choice(d[i]) for i in d])
```

Comment: you might as well just use the built-in `random`, no need for `numpy`

Comment: Yeah, i have amended it. I usally use numpy that's why it came as first option, thanks

Comment: @archer yeah this is a variation of the "naive" way I used, I was hoping for a simpler way